# From which play YouTube video of Al Pacino belongs to in Jack and Jill?

Tags: dialogue, plot-explanation, jack-and-jill

In [Jack and Jill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_and_Jill_(2011_film)), there is a YouTube video of Al Pacino having a nervous breakdown. In that video, what play is he doing? It seems like Shakespeare to me but which play of Shakespeare is it? And when he says "Shut all cell phones off! This is what the man said!!" Who is he referring to as "the man"?

Comment: he's referring to the announcement made before a play starts over the loud speakers asking the audience to turn off their phones, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a Shakespeare play, he's doing [Richard III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_III_%28play%29) (he's also dressed like him). The line he's reading is from act IV, scene IV in the play:

> If I did take the kingdom from your sons, to make amends, I'll give it to your daughter.

As for "the man", it's unclear; bear in mind that he's going nuts. He's looking and pointing up when he says that, so it's possible he means God, Shakespeare, Richard III or some higher up like the director.